# PHP File edits not taking affect after uploading to the server

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP helper class with all static methods. When I add a new method or make
any changes to the file and afterwards upload to server, the server does not detect the changes. I get an error saying

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Class::functionName() does not
>   exist

even though it does exist.
 I've tried restarting Apache Server and also clearing browser cache. I don't have any caching setup on server either.

Comment: The http server picks up modifed files automatically, no need to restart the http server process. There must be some other issue. Could it be that you uploaded your files to another location by accident?

Comment: make sure you are editing on the same server on which you are testing.. also check php version on server and on your local machine

Comment: I checked the upload directory of the file and it's correct. I do have different version of PHP on my local machine and server but I don't see how that could cause methods not being detected. The codebase is compatible with php4.

Comment: I've logged in to ssh and checked the modified date is correct. I've also made changes using vim to ensure I was editing the correct file.

Comment: @hoijui, I would mark as accepted if you answered because it turns out it was a silly mistake of uploading the same file to a different location and autoload was loading the class twice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can, connect to the server with ssh and do some investigation. for example, search for the php file with find, to see if it lies around multiple times, check last modified dates, and of course the contents. also maybe modify the main file of your webpage (for example *index.php*), to verify that you are looking in the right place.